# How can I remove duplicates sorted by traits?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with four columns. In column one is my trait and I don't want any duplicates of the trait. How can I select which one is removed using the duplicate() or unique() function in the dplyr package?

If column 2 = Female I want this row to be kept. If both the duplicates is 1 in column 2 I want the one with the largest number in column 3 to be kept. And if they are identical in column three then I want the one with the highest number in column four to be kept.

So I want to go from this:

```
trait sex sample_size variants 
A F 9 9 
A M 9 9 
B F 6 9
B F 3 9
C F 3 6
C F 3 3
```

To this:

```
trait sex sample_size variants
A F 9 9 
B F 6 9
C F 3 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to `filter` the 'F' in 'sex', then `arrange` the columns 'trait', 'sex' and the numeric columns in `desc`ending and get the `distinct` rows based on 'trait' and 'sex'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(sex == "F") %>%
  arrange(trait, sex, desc(sample_size), desc(variants)) %>% 
  distinct(trait, sex, .keep_all = TRUE)
#  trait sex sample_size variants
#1     A   F           9        9
#2     B   F           6        9
#3     C   F           3        6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(trait = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), sex = c("F", 
 "M", "F", "F", "F", "F"), sample_size = c(9L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L), variants = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont think this works though as duplicates in row 1 are still present

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen  It is based on your example.  If you can show a better example in your post, that would be helpful

Comment: I've tried to update. Basically I have a column of traits eg. hair colour, hight, etc. This is just written in text and I want just one row per trait. Column to i sex and if female is present I want to keep this row over male. If both rows are female I want to keen the row with the largest sample size and if this is also equal I want to keep the row that has the most variants

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen  Please check if the updated solution works

Comment: this leave just an empty data frame. The last solution seemed do remove most of the duplicates but kept two rows when the sex column had two different values

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen   we are also doing the `distinct` on 'sex'.  If you want to remove that as well, use `distinct(trait, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: this seems to work: 
df1 %>% 
  arrange(trait, sex, desc(sample_size), desc(variants)) %>% 
  distinct(trait, .keep_all = TRUE)

Thanks!

Comment: @Gunn-HelenMoen  With that code, do you face any issues

Comment: No that one works as I wanted. Thanks for your help!